# Cannot install Tailwind on Windows Desktop

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, craco

I've sent a program to my coworker so he can run it on his own machine, and when installing the dependencies and attempting "npm start", I'm given the error below.

```
> TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start
 
'TAILWIND_MODE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

I also got this error on my mac months ago, the easy fix was

```
npm install craco
```

however, I have installed craco and every other natural dependency and still get this error.  Is there a compatibility issue with windows or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ***env*** before your command inside ***package.json*** script file:

```
> "env TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start"
```

for example:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "env TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",
```